# Understanding python requests objects

Tags: python, python-requests

I've looked into the following code and i'm trying to understand the following function and how it returns the data.

```
import requests

r = requests.get('https://api.github.com', auth=('user', 'pass'))

print r.status_code
print r.headers['content-type']
```

The above code declares a variable **r**. Does the **r** variable accept an array? is the data passed back to the **r** variable. So accessing the `r.status-code` is status-code store within an array or a returned variable?

Comment: Is this something you specifically don't understand about `requests.get`? Because it works exactly the same as all other assignment operations of any other type of value, in virtually all similar programming languages.

Comment: I am not sure what the question is about. The code **does not** declare a function. It just calls `requests.get()` and stores the returned value in `r`. `status_code` is not in an array - it is part of the returned value `r` (an attribute, in the Python terminology).

Answer (score 2):

The function `requests.get('https://api.github.com', auth=('user', 'pass'))` has an Response-Object as return value. With `r.status_code` you are accessing the attribute of this object. More information you can visit here:
http://www.pythonforbeginners.com/requests/using-requests-in-python

Comment: Ah, so this is oop based python?

Comment: I should look into - https://www.learnpython.org/en/Classes_and_Objects to understand deeper then, thanks

Comment: yes, all variables are referred to as class variables. More information: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/understanding-class-and-instance-variables-in-python-3